# How are my own themes updated?

Tags: themes, installation

Is there a link, or does someone know a way to check what version of my theme my customers are using and how to notify them to update their theme? I am selling a theme that I am hosting myself (NOT submitted to Wordpress) and I'm curious how I can make it update.

If I wasn't clear, if a customer buys my theme and I have updates how can they update the theme from the Wordpress admin panel.

Comment: This issue has been handled a few times here. Feel free to use the site search ;-)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+update+a+purchased+wordpress+theme

Comment: Mind your manners please. If you need to get insulting, then this is the incorrect place to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [ThemeUpdateChecker class](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2011/06/02/automatic-updates-for-commercial-themes/)

Basic outline of the process:

1. Have a fixed spot on your server to both house a little bit of data about the current version and a zip of your theme files.
2. Hook an action into `pre_set_site_transient_update_themes`
3. In that action, ping your server (with something like curl)
4. Compare the versions of both the local and remote themes.

Two more references:

- [Full featured](https://github.com/jeremyclark13/automatic-theme-plugin-update)
- [Simple](https://xparkmedia.com/blog/add-update-notification-selfhosted-premium-themes-plugins/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @tf you are of course correct. His attitude made me lazy. Your comment made me less lazy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your theme from Git or BitBucket Private Repo. There are some good PHP Libraries that will allow you to update your theme from Git/BitBucket without much of a hassle. As mentioned by Pieter, feel free to use site search as well as Google. ;-)

Comment: Relax. Look for "afragen/github-updater". If you don't want to code it yourself then I think there is a paid solution for you called "deployhq.com".